# Difficult riddle I'm stumped on

Tags: riddle

Gosh, this is somewhere over the rainbow, but not under the table +
don't start getting salty if you can't crack it, just try 100 rounds.

Answer (score 3):

Laurel logic is sound, however that would lead me to conclude

> Passwords
>  
>  Passwords need to be salted, are stored in rainbow tables and can be hacked using brute force (with enough computing power)

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is

> Cryptography, or something similar.

---

*Gosh, this is somewhere over the rainbow, but not under the table*

> [Rainbow table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table)

*don't start getting salty if you can't crack it*

> - [Cryptographic salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)), used in preventing rainbow table attacks.

*just try 100 rounds.*

> Do a [brute force attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack)